# Unity3D: Fastest way to go over huge number of points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my issue. I have an array of Vector3 (size > 10,000). My object should go over each points in the shortest period of time. For example, in the code below, the objects moves from one point to another every frame. But when the array of points is big it will take more than 2 minutes to go over every point.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour{

        Vector3[] points = new Vector3[10000];
        int i = 0;
        private void Update()
        {
                transform.position = points[i];
                 i++;
        }
}
```

Is there a faster way to do this? I would appreciate if someone could suggest me a faster way to do this operation.

Comment: "JobSystem" maybe help you . It  use mutil thread to do https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html

Comment: @TimChang Is it gonna work if I export my work to WebGL and open it in browser? cause I heard multi threading doesn't work in some browsers

Comment: I can't think of a normal game reason why you would want to reposition an object repeatedly in a series of points like that.  If you're doing it on each individual game frame, of course it's going to take forever.  If you don't want it to take 2 minutes, why would you translate it exactly once per frame?  Can you give some details about the problem you're trying to solve.  It really sounds like there should be a better way.

Comment: I'm confuse why not foreach all pointers in one frame ,  Only move one position in every frame is waste perfermance , mabe just move 1000 times in one frame ? (So only use 10 frame well done. ) It is not a low performance soultion I guess.

Comment: @JamesHoux Thanks for feedback. So, it's not actually a game but a model where a construction equipment should follow GPS data. There is a scroll bar where the user can jump to certain point. When the users jumps let's say to the last point the truck should get there by following each point.

Comment: Have you considered moving it in fixedupdate? You can play around with the fixedupdate time in the settings to match your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a speed, figure out how much you travel on the current frame by multiplying it by `Time.deltaTime`;

Use `Vector3.MoveTowards` to move toward the next point. Repeat until you run out of distance for that frame or run out of points.

You'll need to be able to leave multiple traces per frame, so put your procedure for adding traces into a `void LeaveTrace(Vector3 position)` method so we can call it where necessary.

You can have a goal index set to determine how to traverse the point array, but make sure you update the source index if you change direction of traversal in the middle of a traversal.

Altogether:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour{

    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[10000];
    public float speed = 1f;
    private int curSourceIndex = 0;

    private int goalIndex = 0; // no goal

    private void Update()
    {
        if (goalIndex != curSourceIndex)
        {
            MoveBus();
        }
    }

    private void MoveBus()
    {
        int step = goalIndex > curSourceIndex ? 1 : -1;

        float distLeft = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        while (distLeft > 0 && curSourceIndex != goalIndex)
        {
            Vector3 curTarget = points[curSourceIndex + step];

            Vector3 curPos = transform.position;

            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(curPos, curTarget, distLeft);

            distLeft -= (newPos-curPos).magnitude;

            if (newPos == curTarget) 
            {
                // Leave trace at each point reached
                LeaveTrace(newPos)

                curSourceIndex += step;
            }

            transform.position = newPos;
        }

    }

    public void SetGoalIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= points.length) return; // or throw/log etc here

        // Do any appropriate modification to curSourceIndex
        if (points[curSourceIndex] != curPos) 
        {
            // If we were going up but we're going down (or back to where we were), 
            // increase source index
            if (goalIndex > curSourceIndex && index <= curSourceIndex) 
            { 
                curSourceIndex +=1;
            }
            // if vice versa, decrease source index
            else if (goalIndex < curSourceIndex && index >= curSourceIndex)  
            {
                curSourceIndex -=1;
            }   
        }

        goalIndex = index;
    }

    void LeaveTrace(Vector3 pos)
    {
        // leave a trace at the pos location
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `while` loop inside `Update`? *Especially* with `|| curTargetIndex >= points.Length` without ever setting curTargetIndex to 0 inside the loop.

Comment: I will add that this assumes the user wants a constant velocity.  For an effective UI, the velocity should probably speed up when the camera is traveling further distances.  The OP should use this code as an example to do a distance calculation before moving the camera to find out how fast he should move the camera.  Also, the given solution assumes linear movement.  A modern UI should seek to have camera ease-in and ease-out.

Comment: Lol woops.  Replace camera with object in my comment.  Logic still applies.  When I read his comment saying "User can jump to a certain point", my mind automatically went to the common pattern where a camera jumps to a point.

Comment: @Ruzihm When my object moves from one point to another it leaves a trace behind. When I tried to implement your code the only trace I see is from start point to end point. I want the trace of the route to be visible. Any suggestion how can I achieve that?

Comment: @Gray_Rhino I included a part that shows where you would need to call your trace procedure. I also wanted to change my answer so you could handle traversing in any direction just by setting the goal index, and it may handle changing goals in the middle of a traversal.  Pretty much everything changed so watch out.